# Flutter & Dart, Constructor before the properties

Tags: class, flutter, dart, constructor

I was watching a course and the instructor always write the constructor first, then the properties, in java, c# and other OOP languages the properties are written first. Is there a reason to write de constructor first?

```
class MyClass{

  MyClass({this.name, this.age});

  final String name;
  final int age; 
}
```

Comment: That's the order required in the Flutter repo style guide (i.e. the style in which the Flutter framework itself is written). https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#constructors-come-first-in-a-class

Answer (score 2):

It is a personal preference, you can continue writing the properties first

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific rule stating the constructor must be declared before the properties. It's a personal preference of the instructor's, I guess, and it shouldn't affect the program.